# Onmouseover child div problem

Tags: javascript, events

I have a small div above (hover) a big one.
I  assign onmouseover and onmouseout events to the wrapper div.
For image caption roll-over animation.

The problem is when the mouse is above the caption itself, causing an unwanted result.
I can't understand why.

How to make it work? (**no jquery**)
must work on all browsers.

[Demo](http://verror.netai.net/test.html)

**Update:**
I have added firebug console log, to a better debugging.
And discovered a new bug: sometimes when you move mouse from outside to container you get a sequence:
-I am over-
-I am out-
-I am over-

Answer (score 2):

`divSmall` isn't a child of `divBig`, so the onmouseover event will not propagate/bubble to `divBig` from `divSmall`.  This leaves you with several options:

- Make `divSmall` a child of `divBig`.
- Add the event handlers to `Container`.
- Add event handlers to `divSmall` that fire the event handlers of `divBig`.

Personally, I would go for options 1 or 2.

Comment: it doesn't work, when the mouse on small div the OutMe is triggered.

Comment: and in IE I get: 'stopPropagation' is null or not an object

Comment: @luppi: Sorry, I rushed through the reading of your source code and thought `divSmall` was a child of `divBig`.  I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Please take a look at my full example that I added to the question